# How to display values from database in real time without refreshing the webpage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, angular2-services

I'm working on an Angular2 project (Resource Management) which requires data from the database (mongoDB) in real time. The basic function of the application is to drag a resource from bench and drop it to a project. After which a button  is clicked which saves these values to the database. The problem is once the database is hit with the values, the same is not showing up unless the page is refreshed. Is there a way where we can pull data from the database without manually refreshing the entire page or pulling the data from DB at regular intervals so that the services have the latest data. I'm attaching my code here: [Resource Management (drag n drop)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xdEU39xON8Awoz_UocPsOkDXZYcWq47Y)

Thank you!!

Comment: Provide us a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @sravan kumar coudn't  understand the exact problrm

Comment: Incomplete question this is !

Comment: @Ajith I'm trying to pull data from the database and display them without actually refreshing the page. Is there a way to pull data asynchronously or at regular time intervals?

Comment: @Kay Sorry about that. Hope this edit gives a better understanding..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data periodically.You can use timer.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.timer = Observable.timer(2000,5000);
 // subscribing to a observable returns a subscription object
 this.sub = this.timer.subscribe(t => this.geData(t));
  }

 geData(t) {
  console.log(t)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could use [socket.io](https://socket.io) for real time update with angular2 and mongodb